# WPF Datagrid - Binding a collection of collections

Tags: wpf, xaml, collections, binding, datagrid

I want to bind a DataGrid to a collection of objects that contain a nested collection, because the number of values for each row is undefined until runtime.

I've a class called *Record*

```
Public Class Record
    Private _timestamp As DateTime
    Private _deviceName As String
    Private _values As List(Of Double)
    Public Property Timestamp As DateTime
        Get
            Return _timestamp
        End Get
        Set(value As DateTime)
            _timestamp = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property DeviceName As String
        Get
            Return _deviceName
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _deviceName = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property Values As List(Of Double)
        Get
            Return _values
        End Get
        Set(value As List(Of Double))
            _values = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Sub New(ByVal timestamp As DateTime, ByVal deviceName As String, ByVal values As List(Of Double))
        Me.Timestamp = timestamp
        Me.DeviceName = deviceName
        Me.Values = values
    End Sub
End Class
```

and a collection of *Record* objects

```
Dim records As ObservableCollection(Of Record)
records = New ObservableCollection(Of Record)
With records
    .Add(New Record(Now, "DEV1", New List(Of Double) From {0.1, 0.2, 0.3}))
    .Add(New Record(Now, "DEV2", New List(Of Double) From {1.1, 1.2, 1.3}))
    .Add(New Record(Now, "DEV3", New List(Of Double) From {2.1, 2.2, 2.3}))
End With
```

I do not know how to bind values coming from the property Values to columns in XAML.

How should I bind the properties to XAML datagrid's columns? And what about headers? How can I set them?

What I want to obtain is

```
+------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| DATE       | DEVICE | VALUE1 | VALUE2 | VALUE3 |
+------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| 2014/10/17 | DEV1   | 0.1    | 0.2    | 0.3    |
| 2014/10/17 | DEV2   | 1.1    | 1.2    | 1.3    |
| 2014/10/17 | DEV3   | 2.1    | 2.2    | 2.3    |
+------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

**EDIT** Following Mike's advice I implemented an ITypedList interface.
Class *Datalog* implements ITypedList and is an ArrayList of *DataLogRecord* objects.
*DataLogRecord* object has 2 properties (Timestamp and DeviceName) and a third property that is *DataLogValueCollection* (that is an ArrayList of *DataLogValue*).

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Public Class DataLog
    Inherits ArrayList
    Implements ITypedList
    Private Function GetItemProperties(ByVal listAccessors() As PropertyDescriptor) As PropertyDescriptorCollection Implements ITypedList.GetItemProperties
        Return TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(GetType(DataLogRecord))
    End Function
    Private Function GetListName(ByVal listAccessors() As PropertyDescriptor) As String Implements ITypedList.GetListName
        Return "DataLogRecord"
    End Function
End Class

Public Class DataLogRecord
    Private _timestamp As DateTime
    Private _deviceName As String
    Private _values As DataLogValueCollection
    Public Property Timestamp As DateTime
        Get
            Return _timestamp
        End Get
        Set(value As DateTime)
            _timestamp = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property DeviceName As String
        Get
            Return _deviceName
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _deviceName = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property Values As DataLogValueCollection
        Get
            Return _values
        End Get
        Set(value As DataLogValueCollection)
            _values = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Sub New(ByVal timestamp As DateTime, ByVal deviceName As String,
                   ByVal values As DataLogValueCollection)
        Me.Timestamp = timestamp
        Me.DeviceName = deviceName
        Me.Values = values
    End Sub
End Class

Imports System.ComponentModel
Public Class DataLogValueCollection
    Inherits ArrayList
    Implements ITypedList
    Private Function GetItemProperties(ByVal listAccessors() As PropertyDescriptor) As PropertyDescriptorCollection Implements ITypedList.GetItemProperties
        Return TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(GetType(DataLogValue))
    End Function
    Private Function GetListName(ByVal listAccessors() As PropertyDescriptor) As String _
    Implements ITypedList.GetListName
        Return "DataLogValue"
    End Function
End Class

Public Class DataLogValue
    Private _value As Nullable(Of Double) = Nothing
    Private _name As String = Nothing
    Public Property Value As Nullable(Of Double)
        Get
            Return _value
        End Get
        Set(value As Nullable(Of Double))
            _value = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property Name As String
        Get
            Return _name
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _name = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Sub New()
    End Sub
    Public Sub New(ByVal value As Nullable(Of Double), ByVal name As String)
        Me.Value = value
        Me.Name = name
    End Sub
End Class
```

Grid definition

```
<DataGrid Name="DataGridValues" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
        Style="{StaticResource DataGridStyle}"
        CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCellEventStyle}"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        ItemsSource="{Binding DataLog}">
</DataGrid>
```

Now the result DataGrid is

```
+------------+------------+--------+--------+--------+
| Timestamp  | DeviceName | Values                   |
+------------+------------+--------+--------+--------+
| 2014/10/17 | DEV1       | (Collection)             |
| 2014/10/17 | DEV2       | (Collection)             |
| 2014/10/17 | DEV3       | (Collection)             |
+------------+------------+--------+--------+--------+
```

First 2 columns are properly created, while values (coming from DataLogValueCollection) are shown as a single column. What am I missing?

Comment: You can expose these 'dynamic' fields using custom property descriptors.  If you know how many value columns you will have by the time you assign the `ItemsSource`, then your best bet would be to bind to a custom collection implementing `ITypedList`.  Alternatively, you could have `Record` implement `ICustomTypeDescriptor`, but support for auto-generating columns is more flaky with that approach.